# Android - Update status bar notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I have created a android application, that polls the server once in two minutes by making use of the Alarm service. After the alarm triggers a Service Intent, that will poll the server for any new data. If new data is available, a status bar notification will be generated using NotificationManager class.

I have few queries here:

1. At first a notification will be generated indicating new data update arrived from server. After two minutes, again new data is available. How to know whether user clicked the old notification or not? By knowing I will decide whether to put "New message arrived" or "2 New messages arrived"
2. How can I update the existing notification from the service intent itself?
3. How can I get the extras and append it in the listview of the Activity? Now each time I click the notification, new listview is created in the Activity and only that message is appended.

PollingServer.class:

```
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).cancelAll();

            Intent notificationIntent= new Intent(this, Messages.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("msg",toastText);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(Messages.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clove)
                            .setContentTitle("My notification")
                            .setContentText(toastText)
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                            .setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Messages.class:

```
            private ListView mainListView;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            final String msg = extras.getString("msg");

            // Find the listView Resource
            mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            mainListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            arrayAdapter.add(msg);

         }
```

Comment: I know that, when created, Notifications have an ID number that yourself can define. WIth that number you can retrieve and edit them.

Comment: @joaquin Ok Lets store that ID in database. How do we know, It should be edited or created. Whether user made the click over that notification and viewed the activity

Comment: You have this line of code: `mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build())` that `1` is the current notification ID of your app. If you launch another Notification with, let's say, number 2, then you'll have two Notifications simultaneously. If you launch another Notification with the 1 number then it will replace the old one.

Comment: Ya i get it. I don't want two notification. I want to update the same notification, if user haven't clicked the notification. If user already clicked, He could have read the old messages, So I will update only the current info in notification.

Comment: Then use the `1` number ever.

Comment: Yup.. But how can i track the user clicks out of AlarmService

Comment: Notifications can be configured with a Pending Intent. An intent that will be launched on user click. DId you read [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)? Everything is said there.